# Magento - addFieldToFilter doesn't choose the right product

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I am currently programming a product configurator module for Magento. Everything is working fine so far besides the core functionality: choosing the right product from the database for the selected attributes. My attributes belong to an attribute group from which the form fields for my configurator are generated, the values I use are the admin fields. The shop language is swedish.

The shop contains one configurable product with simple products associated to it. The simple products don't show individually in the shop. Right now not all combinations of my attributes are existing but it should at least return the right product for one combination I know is existing. First it always returned null, right now it returns all products. How can I achieve to have just product be chosen?

First the attributes didn't even show in the query until I activated "Used in Product Listing".

Thanks in advance for any help :)

This is my getProduct method:

```
public function getProduct($attributes)
{

    Mage::Log($attributes);

    //Get Product Collection
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    $collectionCount = count($collection);

    Mage::Log($collectionCount);

    //Filter for Selected Product
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('doorconfig_enable',array('eq' => 'Yes'));

    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) 
    { 
        $collection->addFieldToFilter($key,array('eq' => $value));
    }

    $selection = $collection->getSelect()->__toString();

    Mage::Log($selection);

    $collectionCount = count($collection);

    Mage::Log($collectionCount);

    $product = $collection->getFirstItem();

    return $product;

}
```

The $attributes parameter contains the POST data which is correctly submitted:

```
[doorconfig_color] => 000000
[doorconfig_type] => lines
[doorconfig_size] => 2500x1800
[doorconfig_remote] => no
[doorconfig_digitalkeypad] => No
[doorconfig_extraremotecontrol] => No
[configdoor_addemergencylock] => No
[doorconfig_insideopeningbutton] => No
[doorconfig_window] => No window
```

"configdoor_addemergencylock" is a typo by my dear collegues, but still read correctly from the database (just if anyone wonders). As I am not good in SQL and not very experienced in Magento, I don't know whether my query is right or wrong:

```
2013-07-20T09:47:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, 
`e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.
`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, 
LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) 
AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, 
`price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`doorconfig_color`, `e`.`doorconfig_color_value`, 
`e`.`doorconfig_type`, `e`.`doorconfig_type_value`, `e`.`doorconfig_size`, 
`e`.`doorconfig_size_value`, `e`.`doorconfig_remote`, `e`.`doorconfig_remote_value`, 
`e`.`doorconfig_digitalkeypad`, `e`.`doorconfig_digitalkeypad_value`, 
`e`.`doorconfig_extraremotecontrol`, `e`.`doorconfig_extraremotecontrol_value`, 
`e`.`configdoor_addemergencylock`, `e`.`configdoor_addemergencylock_value`, 
`e`.`doorconfig_insideopeningbutton`, `e`.`doorconfig_insideopeningbutton_value`, 
`e`.`doorconfig_window`, `e`.`doorconfig_window_value` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` 
AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` 
ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' 
AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (e.doorconfig_color = '000000') 
AND (e.doorconfig_type = 'lines') AND (e.doorconfig_size = '2500x1800') 
AND (e.doorconfig_remote = 'no') AND (e.doorconfig_digitalkeypad = 'No') 
AND (e.doorconfig_extraremotecontrol = 'No') AND (e.configdoor_addemergencylock = 'No') 
AND (e.doorconfig_insideopeningbutton = 'No') AND (e.doorconfig_window = 'No window')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to filter your product collection

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(*);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('doorconfig_enable',array('eq' => 'Yes'));
```

Comment: The advice to use addAttributeToFilter instead of addFieldToFilter was correct, but for the doorconfig_enable I had to use the boolean value to filter correctly like Roman Shopin suggested: `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('doorconfig_enable',array('eq' => 1));` Though the other attributes still don't work if I loop through them by ID:

Comment: foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) 
        {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect($key);
            
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter($key,
                array(
                        'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                                    ->getAttribute($key)
                                    ->getSource()
                                    ->getOptionId($value)
                     )
            );

        }

Answer (score 0):

What type of "doorconfig_enable" attribute? If boolean, use "0" or "1". If "doorconfig_enable" is select attribute, you need to use option id.
So:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('doorconfig_enable')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('doorconfig_enable',array('eq' => 1));

Mage::log($collection->getSize(),null,'custom.log');
```

If you need to get the option ID, checkout [this](http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2009/04/06/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/)

Comment: doorconfig_enable is a Yes/No attribute, so it is a Boolean. I tried using 1 as the value and it works. But for the loop I still have no luck. I tried to get the IDs for all the chosen attribute options like this:

Comment: `foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) 
        {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect($key);
            
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter($key,
                array(
                        'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                                    ->getAttribute($key)
                                    ->getSource()
                                    ->getOptionId($value)
                     )
            );

        }`

Comment: But not all attribute IDs seem to be returned as the query looks like this:

Comment: DEBUG (7): SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`doorconfig_enable`, `e`.`doorconfig_color`, `e`.`doorconfig_color_value`, `e`.`doorconfig_type`, `e`.`doorconfig_type_value`, `e`.`doorconfig_size`, `e`.`doorconfig_size_value`, `e`.`doorconfig_remote`, `e`.`doorconfig_remote_value`, `e`.`doorconfig_digitalkeypad`, `e`.`doorconfig_digitalkeypad_value`, `e`.`doorconfig_extraremotecontrol`, `e`.`doorconfig_extraremotecontrol_value`,

Comment: `e`.`configdoor_addemergencylock`, `e`.`configdoor_addemergencylock_value`, `e`.`doorconfig_insideopeningbutton`, `e`.`doorconfig_insideopeningbutton_value`, `e`.`doorconfig_window`, `e`.`doorconfig_window_value` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` WHERE (e.doorconfig_enable = 1) AND (e.doorconfig_color = '') AND (e.doorconfig_type = '') AND (e.doorconfig_size = '6') AND (e.doorconfig_remote = '') AND (e.doorconfig_digitalkeypad = '') AND (e.doorconfig_extraremotecontrol = '') AND (e.configdoor_addemergencylock = '') AND (e.doorconfig_insideopeningbutton = '') AND (e.doorconfig_window = '')

Comment: The select looks a little odd because of all the backticks interpreted as code markers. It just shows that some of the attribute IDs seem to return an empty value while size returns a proper value. All the attributes are Yes/No and Dropdown fields.

Comment: New clue is that my POST data submits the admin label, but my getOptionId refers to the current store label. My size attribute is the only one with the same values for admin and current store, so this must be the case. How do I get the option ID for the admin label?

Comment: I tried using the default shop labels as my form data and it works like a charm, but for the logic of my module it would be much better if I could get the attribute option ID for the admin label, but how?